# laravel: how to convert or translate the name from hours to hrs or minutes to mins?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I want to know how to translate the name from hours to hrs or minutes to min if using i am carbon?

Like for example: 2 minutes ago to 2 mins ago.
or 2 hours ago to 2 hrs ago
or 1 minute ago to 1 min ago
or 1 hour ago to 1 hr ago

like that

Comment: as of now i am using diffForHumans but the output is minutes.. but i want to output the abbrevation of minutes like min

Comment: Did you try with `shortRelativeDiffForHumans()`?

Comment: the output shortRelativeDiffForHumans is minutes to m...

Comment: You need to use str_replace to replace minute to min, second to sec

Comment: @sta str_replace will produce incorrect strings in many languages.

Comment: @KyleK therw are no any method for **Carbon** without that. Othewise you need to edit the Carbon souce code

Comment: @sta No you don't, see the first example of the doc: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization and se my answer below, which is the proper way to do such things as described in the doc.

Answer (score 1):

So, it's `->diffForHumans`, but you have to add `true`as the third parameter.

For example:
`->diffForHumans(null, CarbonInterface::DIFF_RELATIVE_TO_NOW, true)`
will output a difference from now (as the first parameter is null, it takes `Carbon::now()` as a basis, but you can set a DateTime interface), the second is the type you want (*ago*, *before*, *from now*, etc.), and the `true` is the use of the shortened version of the units.

The third parameter is set at `false` in priority, and it takes what you have in your locale file.

Comment: The short flag does not exactly what the OP wants, it will print "2h ago" instead of the desired "2hrs ago".

Comment: @Remul you're right, as english is not my main language I didn't catch the difference. I guess maybe updating the locale file or creating a clone to change the shortened versions?

Comment: @Lyzvaleska "h" is the correct (standard) short unit for "hour" in English, what you want is actually a custom short variant, see Localization chapter of the doc https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization to see how to customize translations.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Carbon offers this out of the box but it is macroable so you can write your own custom code:

For example add the code below in a service provider (e.g. `AppServiceProvider`)

```
Carbon::macro('shorterDiffForHumans', static function () {
    $diff = self::this()->diffForHumans(...func_get_args());
    return strtr($diff, [ 'second' => 'sec', 'minute' => 'min', 'hour' => 'hr' ]);
});
```

Then use it as:

```
$date->shorterDiffForHumans()
```

Comment: Good enough for English-only application but `$date->locale('fr')->shorterDiffForHumans()` will actually produces `4 hres 30 mines 22 seces` which is void in French. So the correct way is to customize the short units for each languages supported by your application.

Comment: This code has a syntax error near `'hour' => 'hr ]);` (missing an apostrophe after "hr")

Comment: @Khalilullah thanks for bringing it to my attention

Answer (score 1):

Customize the English to create your own "short version":

See the doc: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization

```
$shortVariant = 'en_Short';
$translator = \Carbon\Translator::get($shortVariant);
$translator->setTranslations([
    'h' => ':count hrs',
    'min' => ':count mins',
]);

$date1 = Carbon::create(2018, 1, 4, 1, 13, 00);
$date2 = Carbon::create(2018, 1, 4, 4, 0, 0);

echo $date1->locale($shortVariant)->diffForHumans($date2, ['short' => true, 'parts' => 2]);
```

Output: `2 hrs 47 mins before`

Custom language will work no matter the method you call (diffForHumans, short/relative variants, forHumans called from CarbonInterval, etc.) and it won't break internationalization (for instance, replacing "second" with "sec" on a french input will gives you "seces" which is void) so this is the recommended way over macros/str_replace/strtr solutions.